# Как в VestaCP отключить phppgadmin?

Tags: безопасность, vesta

Сканер показывает наличие критических уязвимостей на phppgadmin. Можно ли его как-то скрыть или вообще отключить? Скорее всего с отключением вряд-ли, т.к. одна из баз использует pgsql. Посоветуйте как выйти из положения? Может делать какое-то полное отключение удаленного доступа к юрл, отключая саму весту? или блокируя порт?

Answer (score 0):

Можно закрыть доступ с помощью пароля на уровне веб-сервера.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Private"
AuthUserFile /usr/share/phpPgAdmin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

в файл */etc/httpd/conf.d/phppgadmin.conf* где-нибудь между строками

```
  <Directory /usr/share/phpPgAdmin/>
  </Directory>
```

и сгенерируйте файл для пароля командой

```
htpasswd -cb /usr/share/phpPgAdmin/.htpasswd <пользователь> <пароль>
```

Перезапустите веб-сервер apache

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

ps: некоторые моменты (типа команды перезапуска или расположение файлов конфигурациий) могут отличаться от версий дистрибутивов.

Comment: @vadim-s-sabinich, а сама vesta при необходимости будет иметь доступ к phpPgAdmin без пароля? Оказывается, у меня та же самая картина и с phpMyAdmin. Внешний доступ к нему мне не нужен (ну разве по паролю - да). Но вот Веста точно будет обращаться к этой админке. И еще одно - у меня не апач, а nginx (((